# changing value of parameter not given in input ports with each loop iteration in simulink

Tags: simulink

Can anybody tell me how to change value of a parameter which is not given in input ports of that block during each iteration of 'while' or 'for' loop  in any block in simulink for example, if i want to plot 'throughput' against 'SNR' which is a parameter in 'awgn channel' block (which takes only data to be transmitted as input, I change 'SNR' parameter manually) how can it be done automatically  with loop iterations?

Comment: Are you running your simulation using a "for" loop in MATLAB or a for iterator block in Simulink?

Comment: I am thinking to use for iterator block.

Comment: If you have not started your design it is better to keep this loop outside Simulink. Use a simple "for" loop in MATLAB and call sim(model_name) inside it. You can change a parameter of block using set_param function. I am assuming you do not need to change SNR within a simulation.

Comment: No, actually I want to calculate throughput against different values of SNR that's why I would have to change value of SNR in different iterations of loop.